# Running a PowerQuery on Google Sheet - keeps failing

Tags: excel, google-sheets, powerquery

I'm trying to run a PowerQuery on a work-related Google Sheet (that I can't share here) so that the data appears in Excel and refreshes when I need it to.

I have published the Google sheet to the web and gotten the link (in web format, not Excel, but this is failing no matter which file format I publish in).

I then go to Data->From Web in Excel and I paste the link to the Google Doc get this:

[Query Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T6jr.png)

As you can see, the data isn't appearing. It should be a table with a bunch of data.

Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 2):

When using Google's File / Publish to the web pop-up, change the 2nd setting from "Web page" to "Microsoft Excel (.xlsx)".  It then builds a link that works without modification in Power Query.

FYI the best in-depth discussion on this topic is on this thread:

http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Integrations-with-Files-and/How-to-connect-google-sheet-to-Power-BI/m-p/205058#M11276

BTW if you have published your Google sheet to the web, then there shouldn't be any obstacle to sharing it here - it's already visible to anyone.